# Using CSS content property with text spanning multiple lines in source code?

Tags: css

Is there a way to make the `content` property in CSS span multiple lines with hard returns? This is just a matter of preference but I'm curious because I try to avoid longer lines of code for readability. JavaScript has the backslash method to span a string multiple lines. Is there a CSS equivalent?

```css
/*/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / 80  CHARS / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
html:before {
  content: 'I generally like to keep my lines of code below 80 characters in length';
}

html:before {
  content: 'I generally like to keep my lines of code 
  below 80 characters in length.';
}
```

The last CSS rule doesn't work because I broke up the string into multiple lines. Is there a way to keep the formatting with hard returns but have it work as intended?

**EDIT** : To be clear, I'm not asking how to enter a line break in the HTML output. This question is about formatting my raw CSS code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> JavaScript has the backslash method to span a string multiple lines. Is there a CSS equivalent?

Quite literally so:

```css
html:before {
  content: 'I generally like to keep my lines of code \
below 80 characters in length.';
}
```

This is documented in [section 4.3.7 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#strings), which says:

> It is possible to break strings over several lines, for aesthetic or other reasons, but in such a case the newline itself has to be escaped with a backslash (\). For instance, the following two selectors are exactly the same:
>
> ```
> a[title="a not s\
> o very long title"] {/*...*/}
> a[title="a not so very long title"] {/*...*/}
> ```

Comment: Funny. When in doubt...try paradigms from other languages.

Comment: @sol acyon: This is just about where the similarities end, though!